# Og:image meta tag doesn't work for dynamic routes in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, vercel

I want to share dynamic route url(https://epiko-regal-invite.vercel.app/battle/123) in social media with meta tags like title desc and image instead of a plain link. but Og:image doesn't show up. It shows up for direct links(https://epiko-regal-invite.vercel.app/battle/).

I am trying to use dynamic routes using next js and I added meta tags in _app.js file as shown below. I hosted the site on vercel. When I share the url (https://epiko-regal-invite.vercel.app/battle/123) on social media like whatsapp, it should show info given in the meta tags like image, title and description. This works perfectly fine for direct routes in the pages dir but for dynamic routes og:image is not visible while sharing link on social media. I am confused what's wrong. Please help.

meta tags in _app.js file:
[image]

folder structure:
[image]

direct route links vs dynamic route link share on whatsapp:
[image]

Comment: FB debug tool appears to read the og:image fine, https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fepiko-regal-invite.vercel.app%2Fbattle%2F123

Comment: yes. im not sure if dynamic routes handle meta tags differently. couldn't find this info anywhere.